# Mysql database security

Tags: mysql, security

In a web system anyone, who gets access to the DB, can make changes in the account of any user (change posts, etc). 
Is there any way to prevent this problem?
Hashing of the DB is not the way, as it's changed dynamically.
Increasing the security of the server is obvious advice, however there is no absolutely secure computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Limit root** (and any other `SUPER`-privileged user) to

```
GRANT ... TO root@localhost ...
```

That prevents access from other servers.  You should hand out `SUPER` to very few people, and they should be aware of their responsibility.  The application should *not* have `SUPER`.

**Limit application** logins to the one database it uses:

```
GRANT ... ON dbname.* ...
```

That way, someone who hacks into the application code can't get past `dbname`.  This can be further refined via either of these:

```
GRANT SELECT ON dname.* ...    -- "read only"
GRANT ... ON dname.tblname ... -- "just one table"
```

The **readonly** may also need 'safe' things like

```
GRANT SELECT, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ON dname.* ...    -- "read only"
```

As you say, there is **no absolute security**.  My point here is there you can do a few things to slow hackers down.  (Same goes for honest people goofing.)

In rare cases, you may need the application to do something available only to `root`.  this can be done via a "Stored Procedure" that has **`SECURITY DEFINER`** (and root defines it).  That will expose *only* what the SP does, which might, for example, be one particular action on one particular table.

Comment: Thanks! May I somehow create a user, and allow changes to be made only from 1 IP? That's to say, during authentification not only the username and password are required, but also correct IP?

Comment: `GRANT SELECT, INSERT, ... ON ... TO Sonya@'1.2.3.4';` plus `GRANT SELECT ON ... TO Sonya@*;` -- read from anywhere; insert only from that IP.

Comment: Thanks a lot! May I somehow restrict the area of connections only to corporate computers? That's to say, even if a hacker finds the login and password of the user, he can't get access if he is not in the network?

Comment: `Sonya@'1.2.3.%`` or `Sonya@'your.domain.com'`.  See the documentation for more choices, perhaps.

Comment: Thanks, Rick! As I understood, in your example IP is related to the server adress. However I'm talking about the IP of those people, who wants to connect. That's to say, from one computer I would be able to connect, however from another, with different IP, the access will be denied. Is it possible?

Comment: The IP in a `GRANT` is the _client_ ip address.  `GRANT ... Sonya@'1.2.3.4'` lets you come in from 1.2.3.4, but not from 1.2.3.5.  The _server_ IP is mentioned here:  `mysql -h 9.8.7.6` (or something else for Java/PHP/...)